# Bunn coffee maker parts cannot be identified

Tags: coffee

My Bunn Thermofresh coffee maker is five years old, has been thoroughly cleaned and is still overflowing. I have done every procedure to de-lime it, and I replaced the sprayer with the one in the lower right corner of this photo, but to no avail.

[image: Coffee maker parts]

However, I cannot determine what these other parts are for: specifically the beige thing and the one hole black button thing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where exactly is the unit overflowing? And, it's hard to see these parts; do you have a better picture?

Comment: And, where did these parts come from? If they came from the coffee maker, why can't they go back where they came from?

Comment: http://www.bunnomatic.com/home-support/customer-service

Comment: I requested a new sprayer and these parts were in the package without  a diagram or explanation

Comment: The two rubber washers may be part of the anti spill sealing system. Look for the old ones inside the coffee dripper above the part at lower left. Might be one on each side of the spring. There *might be a place for that beige part up there, but I've never seen a similar piece. Looks like it snaps in somewhere.